# Reverse MATCH with a non existing value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, lookup

I have data in Excel in the following format:

```
Column A    Column B
20/03/2018  300
21/03/2018  200
22/03/2018  100
23/03/2018  90
24/03/2018  300
25/03/2018  200
26/03/2018  100
27/03/2018  50
28/03/2018  90
29/03/2018  100
30/03/2018  110
31/03/2018  120
```

I would like to get the date where the minimum of B would never be under 99 again chronologically. It the example above, that would happen the 29th of March.

If I try to get it with:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(99,B1:B12,-1))
```

the value returned is 22/03/2018 as it is the first occurrence found, searched from top to bottom.

In this case it would be perfect to be able to do a reverse match(e.g. a match that searches from bottom to top of the range) but this option is not available. I have seen that it is possible to do reverse matches with the lookup function but in that case I need to provide a value that is actually in my data set (99 would not work).

The workaround I have found is to add a third column like the following (with the minimum of the upcoming value of B going down) and index match on top it.

```
Column A    Column B  Column C
20/03/2018  300       50
21/03/2018  200       50
22/03/2018  100       50
23/03/2018  90        50
24/03/2018  300       50
25/03/2018  200       50
26/03/2018  100       50
27/03/2018  50        50
28/03/2018  90        90
29/03/2018  100       100
30/03/2018  110       110
31/03/2018  120       120
```

Is there a way of achieving this without a third column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AGGREGATE` function is great for problems like these:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,4,(B2:B13<99)*A2:A13,1)+1
```

*What are those numeric arguments?*

> - `14` tells the function to replicate a `LARGE` function
> - `4` to ignore no values (this function can ignore error values and other things)

More info [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/aggregate.php). I checked it works below:

[image]

If your dates aren't always consecutive, you'll need to add a bit more to the function:

```
=INDEX(A1:A12,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,(B1:B12<99)*A1:A12,1),A1:A12,0)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`=INDEX(A1:A12,LARGE(IF(B1:B12<=99,ROW(B1:B12)+1),1))`

This is an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar)

Builds an array of the row 1 below results that are less than or equal to 99. Large then returns the largest row number for index.